# Camel FTP component with Blueprint runs always

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to get files from a remote ftp server by using camel-ftp component. I am using blueprint to develop my example.

If I implement that as in the examples in main page of component (http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html ), I have no problem with it.

My problem is that when I can only use this component as comsumer and it is always listening the remote directory.

(< from uri="sftp://test@remoteServer//var/opt/test?password=secret"/>).

The thing I want to do is that trigger this route with seda and after one run, it should get the files to local directory and then continue with next route like below (It isnot working ordinarily because of double from in a route).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

```
<camelContext id="blueprintContext" trace="false"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="source_quartz">
        <from
            uri="quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?trigger.repeatInterval=10000&amp;trigger.repeatCount=0" />
        <to uri="seda:step1" />
    </route>

    <route id="ftp_ruote">
        <from uri="seda:step1" />
        <from uri="sftp://test@remoteServer//var/opt/test?password=secret"/>
        <to uri="file:///local/test" />
        <to uri="seda:step2" />
    </route>
    .
    .
    .
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at route policy, which allows you to associate a route with eg a quartz route policy, where you can configure start|stop intervals when a route should be active.

See the following links. Then you only need 1 route:

- http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy
- http://camel.apache.org/scheduledroutepolicy.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. As I am new in camel, there may be sth i could not get. I am using ftp to get files from a remote server. My problem is when I use ftp as comsumer, it always listen the directory, the thing i need to do is trigger this ftp route after some processes like ssh&parse&blabla. I do not want ftp to listen the directory always. I want to get files only when i trigger it and run ftp only once then continue with next route. (Basically I want to use ftp component as producer, but i could not find a example in this way, I hope i am more clear now)